# Markdown Prettify

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, markdown

I'm using `PageDpwn` markdown on our project for easy content input and code snippets. I've gotten to a point where I print out `markdown`and convert it into HTML. I use jQuery `$.ajax` to retrieve the markdown from the database and convert it on the fly. Ofcourse this is not ideal. I would like to print out straight HTML from the database, but it so happens that when I do that I have to use `PHP` print functions which output code snippets as:

```
<--?php # Code ?-->
```

This is very unfortunate. So I am converting the markdown to HTML in the page view.

```
<script>
var id = $('input[name=id]').val();
var html = '';

$.ajax({
    url: BASE_DIR + 'pages/get_post/' + id,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        html = data;
        var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
        Markdown.Extra.init(converter, {
            extensions: "all",
            highlighter: "prettify"
        });

        $('#html').html(converter.makeHtml(html));      }
});
</script>
```

As you can see I am using prettify for syntax highlighting. In markdown I succeed in it by using

````
```php
Code block here
```
````

I attempted using:

```
<pre><code>Code block here</code></pre>
```

with classes, but the code block < > tags get commented out. So, my problem is that I have to load `prettify.js` as well as `run_prettify.js` on the bottom of the page otherwise it syntax highlighting or line numbering won't fire. On my body onload I have:

```
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
```

It get no console errors with this but for some weird reason, a fraction of the time the syntax highlighting doesnt fire. I have to reload the page a few times after which it does. Then it works for a while, or perhaps a while longer, but this odd behaviour keeps happening. Anyone know why?

Comment: Is your browser showing any errors? Check the console to find out.

Comment: No, as previously stated.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was to not use Javascript and use a PHP library for markdown to convert the content to HTML. It convered HTML inside a code block the right way using ASCII characters. I adjusted the library a bit to provide Prism.js syntax highlighting and line numbering.